# ORACLE - missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following query which shows me the error of missing keyword in Oracle:

```
DECLARE
  RESULT VARCHAR2(100);
  n number;
BEGIN

  for r in (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM TST_REFRESH) LOOP

    execute immediate 'select count(*) into n from ' || R.TABLE_NAME;

    IF N = 0 THEN 
      dbms_output.put_line('Table Empty ' || r.TABLE_NAME);
    ELSE
      dbms_output.put_line('Table Not Empty' || r.TABLE_NAME);  
    END IF;

  END LOOP;

END;
```

What would be the error?

Comment: `IF N = 0 THEN` shoud not be `IF n = 0 THEN`?

Comment: @Ormoz:  Oracle PL/SQL identifiers are not case-sensitve (but a good idea to keep the case consistent anyway)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to return a value from an `execute immediate`.  Having `into n` in the string is not one of them.

So, one thing you need to fix is this call.  Instead:

```
@sql := 'select count(*) from ' || R.TABLE_NAME;
execute immediate @sql into n;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error: You don't have to write 'into' in your query. 
But you are able to append it to your call of 'execute'. 
This query should work:

```
@query := 'select count(*) from ' || R.TABLE_NAME;
execute immediate @query into n;
```

Comment: Your answer is pretty much identical to Gordon's who answered 4 minutes before you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code you are thinking

```
declare
  result number;
  n number;
begin
  for r in (select table_name from user_tables where rownum < 3) loop
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || r.table_name
      into n;
    if n = 0 then
      dbms_output.put_line('Table Empty ' || r.table_name);
    else
      dbms_output.put_line('Table Not Empty cont ' || n || ' : ' || r.table_name);
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```